# Check for two identical string elements in a Python array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of strings as follow:

> [a1,a2,a1,a3,a2]

I want to find the similar strings and put them in to a new array as below:

> [a1,a2]

I am new to Python. Please give me an idea on how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by array you mean list in python-:

```
s = ["a1","a2","a1","a3","a2"]
duplicates = [x for x in s if s.count(x) > 1]
myl = list(set(duplicates))
print myl
```

output `['a1', 'a2']`

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution using [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
s = ["a1","a2","a1","a3","a2"]
c=collections.Counter(s)
print dict(c.most_common(len(c)-1)).keys()
['a1', 'a2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is *O(nlog(n))* approach to find duplicates. Initial list is sorted ( *O(nlog(n))* ) so that duplicate elements in adjacent places. Then simple *O(n)* iteration is possible to find duplicates.

```
s = ["a1","a2","a1","a3","a2"]
s.sort() # sort changes initial list
new_list = []
prev = (None, False)
for x in s:
    if prev == (x, False):
        new_list.append(x)
        prev = (x, True)
    else:
        prev = (x, False)
print new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the performance though - but it works

```
s = ["a1","a2","a1","a3","a2"]
i=0
common=[]
for i in range(0,len(s)):
  if s[i] not in common and s[i] in s[i+1:]:
    common.append(s[i])
```